# Issue with a function call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, function-call

I am having some trouble calling a function in Swift.
At first look, it seems like usual code (meaning similar to things I have done in the past with no problem). But seing the compiler message, I must be missing some subtlety.

First here is the error I get:

```
'NSManagedObject' is not convertible to 'MyViewController'
```

Then follows the relevant code:

1) Class containing the called function:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ....
    func myVCFunction(_ theData: NSManagedObject) {
        .... // Do some useful work.
    }
}
```

2) The file containing another function, calling the first function (mentioned in 1).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

..... Some useful functions.

func otherCustomFunc(_ dataUnit: NSManagedObject) {
    .... // Do some useful work.
    MyViewController.myVCFunction(dataUnit) // Line getting the error message.
}
```

I do not understand the error message.
Why should 'NSManagedObject' be convertible to 'MyViewController' here?

I'd be glad if somebody could point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create an instance of MyViewController like below:

 import Foundation
    import UIKit

    func otherCustomFunc(_ dataUnit: NSManagedObject) {
        let myViewController = MyViewController()
        myViewController.myVCFunction(dataUnit)
    }
```

Comment: Oh! Very true. I had completely missed that. I now use this syntax: "MyViewController().myVCFunction(dataUnit)" and it works. Thanks for the reminder.